# HTML text File saving href inks to file

Tags: python, bash

I have a huge HTML data file and I want  to save all href link that belong to  “MyInvoice” and  “ID” to separate text file

I don't wont to save “support” and “Otherdocs” href link

data look like this ,  Doc 1 , Doc 2  ,Doc 3 and so on ,

here is sample data

```
Doc : 1

<td>MyInvoice</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>MYINVOICE.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile/77545"></a></td>

<td>support</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>support.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile//6hhh56546"></a></td>


<td>ID</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>ID.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile//6546ssfdsf6"></a></td>
        
Doc : 2

<td>MyInvoice</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>MYINVOICE.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile/1j2a87978hafffa3o"></a></td>


<td>support</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>support.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile/654645645"></a></td>

<td>Otherdocs</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>Otherdocs.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile/6546ssssssss56564564565446"></a></td>

Doc : 3

<td>MyInvoice</td>
<td>randomnumber123445646578dsadsa7</td>
<td>MYINVOICE.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile/123"></a></td>

<td>support</td>
<td>randomnumber1234456465787</td>
<td>support.pdf</td>
<td><a href="/file/myfile//6546ssssssss56546"></a></td>
```

Comment: `<td>` tags without any `<table>`? Kinda hard structure to parse using any HTML parser like Beautifulsoup

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

finally managed to short all href using grep and sed

grep -iRh -A 4 -e "MyInvoice" -e "ID" file.txt  |grep "file" |sed 's/">.*//' |sed -r 's/(.{7})//'

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '/(>MyInvoice<)|(>ID<)|(>support<)|(>Otherdocs<)/ { # Extract the html type
                    typ=gensub(/(<td>)(.*)(<\/td>)/,"\\2",$0) # Set the type in a variable typ
                } 
        $0 ~ /href/ && (typ=="ID" || typ="Otherdocs") { 
                    href=gensub(/(^.*")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0); # When we come to the href line, process when html type is ID or Otherdocs. Use gensub to extract the actual href link
                    print href # Print the link
                } ' file
```

One liner:

```
awk '/(>MyInvoice<)|(>ID<)|(>support<)|(>Otherdocs<)/ { typ=gensub(/(<td>)(.*)(<\/td>)/,"\\2",$0)} $0 ~ /href/ && (typ=="ID" || typ="Otherdocs") { href=gensub(/(^.*")(.*)(".*$)/,"\\2",$0);print href } ' file
```